# Field variations at boundary - Glass of water problem

Tags: field-theory, boundary-conditions, variational-calculus

My question is very simple: if I have a vector field $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\boldsymbol{x})$ defined inside an $n$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}_n$ to which $\boldsymbol{x}$ belongs, why should it be $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\partial\mathcal{M}_n)=0$? What I mean with this abuse of notation is, why should the variation of a field be null at the spatial boundaries of a system?

I read for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536191/), but didn't help. I imagined a very simple system:

Consider a glass of water. I take the height of the surface point by point in every temporal instant and I compare the measure with a reference; I so obtain a field $h(t,\boldsymbol{x})$ that associates an height $h$ to every point $\boldsymbol{x}$ of the bidimensional surface for every time instant.

But if I want to describe the temporal evolution of the perturbed water surface I (apparently) cannot consider $h(t,\partial\mathcal{M}_2)=0$, because water it's free to move at the boundaries: just take a glass of water and prove it! At the same time, just outside the boundaries the problem is not defined, so I don't get the passage from physics to strict mathematics.

So, is it possible to define problems with $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\boldsymbol{x})\neq 0$ for some $\boldsymbol{x}\in\partial\mathcal{M}_n$, or it's not? What would happen in the glass of water problem?

Comment: Exactly this problem is solved in detail in section 1.4 of the book _Mathematics for Physics_ by Stone and Goldbart, which is available [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PG_MS_MfP.htm). It may help you understand what Qmechanic has been trying to tell you.

Comment: @TomášBrauner That's a very interesting book thanks! I think what are you referring to is between page 4 and 5, but I had not quite understood it, I may need to think about it. At the same time, in the glass of water problem, what would happen? 1) It isn't solvable with Euler-Lagrange equations because its variation isn't null at the boundaries 2) Posing $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\partial\mathcal{M}_n)=0$ it's just mathematics and doesn't mean that the field will not vary *near* the domain boundaries (in that case maybe there should be a discontinuity). What's the answer, is there another? Thanks

Comment: Please read the section I pointed you to: it's on pages 33-35. It explains how the boundary condition describing the free water surface arises from the variational principle. It is _not_ the Dirichlet boundary condition that you are trying to impose. It is the natural boundary condition of the variational problem.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I didn't read the "1.4"! Yes it's my problem! I'm not very quick understanding things so I will need more time, but your suggestion is very useful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. FWIW, [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) boundary conditions (BCs) are not the only type of [BCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). There are also e.g. [Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) or [Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition) BCs. The relevant BCs depends on the physical system at hand. This is true even if no variational formulation exists.
2. In the context of a variational problem, say a [stationary action formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), if the Lagrangian depends on spacetime derivatives of the fields, it is necessary to impose [essential or natural](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110506/11127) BCs, such that the [functional/variational derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) exist. Or equivalently, such that [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) can be derived.

Comment: Ok, but why to get Euler-Lagrange equations for the field should I make this assumption?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) of the EL equations?

Comment: Yes I think, I'm trying to understand in the context of field theory what I didn't understand in the classical mechanics course, even because everything here has bigger consequences. In Euler-Lagrange equations derivation I use the Hamilton's stationary action principle and multidimensional divergence theorem, thanks to which part of the integral on the manifold becomes and integral on the boundaries. I put $\boldsymbol{\phi}(\partial\mathcal{M}_{n+1})=\boldsymbol{0}$, this time considering also time $t$ as a variable, but I don't understand exactly for what reason.

Comment: So you are saying that in order to give sense of the fact that the lagrangian depends on the field, but the field can vary differently point to point, I introduce the notion of functional derivative; just asking in every point how the field changes and communicating this information to the lagrangian, in a way. But to make this functional derivative exist (what do you mean?), I should put $\boldsymbol{\phi}(\partial\mathcal{M}_{n+1})=\boldsymbol{0}$. But why??

Comment: Do you know the definition of a functional/variational derivative?

Comment: Not in the most formal way; I just understand the intuitive fact that lagrangian depends on the whole field, but the field depends on the spatial position and so I can define $$\delta L\left(t,\left\{\boldsymbol{\phi}\right\}_{\boldsymbol{x}}(t),\left\{\dot{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\right\}_{\boldsymbol{x}}(t)\right)\doteq\int\limits_{\mathcal{M}_n}\text{d}^nx\left(\delta\phi^\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{x})\frac{\delta L}{\delta\phi^\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{x})}+\delta\dot{\phi}^\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{x})\frac{\delta L}{\delta\dot{\phi}^\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{x})}\right)$$

Comment: Ok, in your above equation we should mention for clarity that $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$ are here independent fields, and there is no integration over time $t$. In order to manipulate the infinitesimal variation on the LHS into the RHS form, you need to impose essential or natural BCs.

Comment: Ok, I follow you here. But why just that precise BC? What would happen if my problem is the glass of water? Or, in another way, what if the field behaves like the water in the glass; how could I know that a priori?

Comment: What precise BCs?? They are not unique.

Comment: I mean why just precisely $\boldsymbol{\phi}(\partial\mathcal{M}_n)=\boldsymbol{0}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a simpler problem: the vibrations of a string. We will describe it with the following Lagrangian density
$$\mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_a\phi\partial^a\phi\,.$$
The equation of motion is
$$0 = \partial_t^2\phi - \partial_x^2\phi\,.$$
The solution of this equation is any function of the form
$$\phi = f(t + x) + g(t - x)\,.$$
We must now choose boundary conditions to determine the physical set of functions $f$ and $g$. One possibility, as you point out, is that $\phi$ must be zero on the boundary. In this case, the solutions are standing waves. Another possibility is periodic boundary conditions, so that $\phi(0) = \phi(L)$ where $L$ is the physical extent of the system. Another common choice is that the first spatial derivative of $\phi$ is zero on the boundary. This sets the momentum transfer into the boundary to zero while still allowing the ends of the string to move.

I will now provide the general solution to the wave equation in each of these three scenarios. First, if the string is fixed on the boundary,
$$\phi = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n t}{L} + \delta_n\right)\,.$$
Second, periodic boundary conditions
$$\phi = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n \sin\left(\pi n\frac{x - t}{L} + \delta_n\right)\,.$$
Third, first derivative set to zero on the boundary
$$\phi = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n \cos\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n t}{L} + \delta_n\right)\,.$$
Here $a_n$ are arbitrary constant coefficients, determined at some initial time.

Ultimately, the point is that you have the freedom to choose whatever boundary conditions you like, so long as they leave no residual freedom. For example, I could mix boundary condition types by saying the left end of the string must be fixed while the right end of the string must have zero first derivative. However, I could not fix one end of the string while leaving the other end "free."

Comment: What I don't understand is that why do I choose just $\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\partial\mathcal{M}_n)=\boldsymbol{0}$ or at least $\delta\boldsymbol{\phi}(t,\partial\mathcal{M}_n)=\boldsymbol{0}$ to obtain Euler-Lagrange equations?

Comment: You must ensure that the physical trajectory is a fixed point of the action. When you have a boundary term in your action, it must also vanish as the variation $\delta\mathbf{\phi}$ is taken to $0$. The set of physical variations at the boundary correspond to the set of physical boundary conditions.